# Wordpress Language file is not being loaded

Tags: wordpress, translation, loading

I seem to have a problem loading Wordpress language files into my custom theme.

In functions.php I have the following code in my setup:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'theme_textdomain', get_template_directory() . '/langs' );
```

In my stylesheet I have the textdomein defined:

```
Text Domain: theme_textdomain
```

In my theme folder I have a folder /langs with 2 different file types:

en_GB.mo
nl_NL.mo

Default language of my theme is nl_NL.

In one of my templates I use:

```
<?= __('Zoeken'); ?>
```

Just to test I added a translation of this in both language files:

For en_GB = search, for nl_NL = zoeken2. However, both nl_NL and en_GB are not being loaded by the theme. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What `WPLANG` value do you have in your `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to specify your theme domain in your call to the `__()` function.  I don't think it's picked up automatically from your stylesheet header.  So rather than

```
<?= __('Zoeken'); ?>
```

try

```
<?= __('Zoeken', 'theme_textdomain'); ?>
```